# Compute the shortest distance in a matrix

Tags: algorithm

An matrix of chars is given as follows:

```
#########
#P......#
####..###
##P....##
#.......#
#########
```

How to find the shortest distance between P and P? The distance is defined as the total number of steps when moving from P to P.
It is allowed to move by one step vertically or horizontally.
In the matrix, '#' stands for obstacles that you can not get through, '.' stands for the open block that you can pass.

It is easy to find the distance by simply DFSing the matrix from P to P. But is there more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: DFS does not always find the shortest path. BFS does.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat A* does not always find the shortest path

Comment: @user2040251 You are right.

Comment: A* most certainly does find the shortest path if you use an admissible heuristic.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Would you please show me how to use an admissible heuristic. As I have known, the key equation in A* is F = G + H, where H is estimated distance from the point to the destination. Now that it is an estimated value, how can we say that A* will always find the shortest path? I am new to A* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the direction to the target and always start looking for a path in that direction. For simple matrices like the one given, a recursive solution will find the path right away, not taking a single step out of the way. For more complex matrices it could of course be fooled to go down dead ends, so then a parallel approach might be better.

Here's what the recursive approach could look like in C#:

```
public static int Distance(string[] matrix, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY, int fromX, int fromY) {
  // show where we are
  Console.WriteLine(x + ", " + y);
  // check for target
  if (x == targetX && y == targetY) return 0;
  // determine valid moves
  List<Point> move = new List<Point> {
    new Point(-1, 0),
    new Point(1, 0),
    new Point(0, -1),
    new Point(0, 1),
  };
  move = move.Where(t => x + t.X != fromX || y + t.Y != fromY).ToList();
  move = move.Where(t => matrix[y + t.Y][x + t.X] != '#').ToList();
  // give up if we are in a dead end
  if (move.Count == 0) return 1000;
  // calculate direction towards target
  double dirX = (targetX - x);
  double dirY = (targetY - y);
  double distance = Math.Sqrt(dirX * dirX + dirY * dirY);
  dirX /= distance;
  dirY /= distance;
  // put moves towards the target first
  move = move.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs(t.X - dirX) + Math.Abs(t.Y - dirY)).ToList();
  // look for paths
  foreach (Point p in move) {
    int d = Distance(matrix, x + p.X, y + p.Y, targetX, targetY, x, y) + 1;
    if (d < 1000) return d;
  }
  return 1000;
}
```

Main:

```
string[] matrix = new string[]{
  "#########",
  "#P......#",
  "####..###",
  "##P....##",
  "#.......#",
  "#########"
};

// find starting and ending points
List<Point> p = new List<Point>();
for (int y=0;y<matrix.Length;y++) {
  for (int x=0;x<matrix[y].Length;x++) {
    if (matrix[y][x] == 'P') {
      p.Add(new Point(x,y));
    }
  }
}

// get distance
int d = Distance(matrix, p[0].X, p[0].Y, p[1].X, p[1].Y, -1, -1);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Output:

```
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1
4, 2
4, 3
3, 3
2, 3
7
```